# Life of final local variable

Tags: java, inner-classes

Is the life of final local variable(inside a method) same as other local variables i.e. do they die as soon as the method call is over with the stack deleted ?
 If it is so then how can we aceess a final local variable inside the method local class but other local variables cannot be?
Please clarify my query.

Comment: They are as other variables, but inner classes require for access that they are final. The motivation is, that assigning to such a variable should not happen on the stack (the method could already have returned).addresses, where the name points to.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an instance of an anonymous inner class, you are effectively creating a **closure**, a special language construct that is said to "close over" the local variables. What happens under the hood is that the value of the final variable is copied into a synthetic instance variable of your anonymous instance. The stack-allocated final variable itself dies with the method, as usual.